# Return different list depending on edittext String

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a `listview` conatining clothes items ..the listview will appear after the `button` `"enter"` under `edittext` will be clicked ..thelistitems will be different depending on what is the string(colors) on `edittext` (PS: the string in Listview are name and refrence of clothes!)..

for exemple:
if user choses in `edittext`: "Color1, Color2, "
a `list` will appear with a name and refrence of clothes that contain those colors: "Item1, Item2"
Because Item1 and Item2 are the only ones to contain the color1 and color2!
The list of possible Items(clothes) are 100, and Possible input in edit text are 6 colors (Color1, Color2, Color3, Color4, Color5, Color6) ..every time the user choses a set of color, the list will be displayed with the possible Items than contain those colors! ( as explained here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8SbN.png)

PS: i've already created a custom edittext and use the adapter with the different strings(Color1..Color6) and i know how to get the string from the edittext ..but how to create update the listview with different items w depending on the string(chosen colors) of the edittext is the priblem! Thanks!
How to that? i've searched on internet on similar exemples with no luck..

This is my code so far:
MainActivity.java

```
public class DecisionTree extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = DecisionTree.class.getSimpleName();
    TextView txt,txt2;
    com.mycardboarddreams.autocompletebubbletext.MultiSelectEditText editText;
    String data;
    private ListView listView;
    private ItemAdapter itemListAdapter;
    private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_decision_tree);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.diseases_list_container);

        itemListAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, this);
        listView.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // add some items
        itemList.add(new Item("Jeans Refnum 2520"));
        itemList.add(new Item("T shirt Refnum 1220"));
            .
.
.
.
.
A long list of 100 items

        //add new items and changes to adapter
        itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Text
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt.setText("Given a set of clinical features, this tool should provide you with a reasonable and relevant differential diagnsosis (not the definitive diagnosis!)");
        txt2.setText("Remember, this tool adds to your diagnostic skills and serves as an educational aid. It is not meant to replace your clinical judgement.");


       //the edittext
        editText = (com.mycardboarddreams.autocompletebubbletext.MultiSelectEditText) findViewById(R.id.auto_text_complete);

        //Add some sample items
        List<SampleItem> sampleItems = Arrays.asList(
                new SampleItem("Blue"),
                new SampleItem("Red"),
                new SampleItem("Orange"),
                new SampleItem("Yellow"),
                new SampleItem("vert"),
                new SampleItem("rouge")
        );

        editText.addAllItems(sampleItems);


        //Get the ListView associated with the MultiSelectEditText
        ListView list = editText.getListView();

        //Add it to a FrameLayout somewhere in the activity
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        list.setLayoutParams(params);


        final FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.auto_list_container);
        frame.addView(list);



        // The output
        //frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.auto_list_container2);

        //Set a listener on bubble clicks
        //editText.setBubbleClickListener(new com.mycardboarddreams.autocompletebubbletext.MultiSelectEditText.BubbleClickListener<SampleItem>() {

           /* @Override
            public void onClick(SampleItem item) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Item: " + item.getReadableName());
                Toast.makeText(DecisionTree.this, item.getReadableName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //displayListPatho();

            }
        });*/

           //-----------------------------------------END ONCREATE
    }

    public void blahblah (View view) {
        data= editText.getText().toString();
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(DecisionTree.this, data,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I acheived what i want with making this code:
1/ created a list with adapter
2/ on each click the items on adapter are removed( `clearAdapter();`) and new items are added `(itemList.add(new Item("Jenny"));)` depending on string from edit text`( if (data.equals("Epistaxis, "))`. and after the adapter is notified with        `itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Ps: blahblah (`=Button OnClick`) ..

```
   public void blahblah (View view) {
        data= editText.getText().toString();
        if (data.equals("Epistaxis, ")){
        clearAdapter();
        itemList.add(new Item("Jenny"));
        itemList.add(new Item("Bladna"));
        itemList.add(new Item("Drafat"));
        itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(DecisionTree.this, Figures.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    //code specific to 2nd list item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Place Your Second Option Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (position == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Place Your Third Option Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }); }
        else if (data.equals("Nasal Discharge, ")) {
            clearAdapter();
            itemList.add(new Item("Jenny2"));
            itemList.add(new Item("Bladna2"));
            itemList.add(new Item("Drafat2"));
            itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Very long question, but it's not clear exactly what do you want? 
If I understand right, you should do somthing like that:
Get your `String string` from EditText.

```
String[] items = string.split(" ");
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What a problem with that?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XwHTmGY.png i've created this pic to explain my goal more ..i don't want to display the chosen colors in edit text in a list! ..i'm trying to display a custom listitems with a text different from that in edittext ..but chosing something will trigger which text to appear in the listview ..Understand betternoew?

Comment: What means chose from EditText? Usually users write somting there.

Comment: Yeah ..write something and then display something different from what is written in edittext..do you know how to that? thanks

Comment: I'm trying to understand your goal, but it's difficult. Why do you need that logic? Write one - than display somthing different...

Comment: okey let suppose you're a customer ..and you want to buy a t-shirt with blue color ..you'll go to edittext and you'll write blue ..and you'll get all possible t-shirt with same color that you have chosen (in a listview) + their reference ..better now? ..Thanks again for willing to help me!

Comment: Think you should do it with SQLDB where there are many find filters, with ListView...it' will be difficult. But you can try to go finding for all Array elements, and display coincidences

Comment: I solved my query ..i created a listview and clear all data from adapter then added a new items list everytime ..thanks dude

Comment: ..Please see my answer, and do you think it can be optmised using Sqlite Database and how?